# sp_Blitz "Too Much Free Memory" on seldom-used SSRS instance

Tags: memory, ssrs, sp-blitz

sp_Blitz (20160715) is reporting "Too Much Free Memory" on a seldom-used 2012 SP2 CU12 test instance (Developer Edition) that only contains the databases created and used by SSRS. The Details are:

> 0GB of free memory inside SQL Server's buffer pool, which is 0GB. You
>   would think lots of free memory would be good, but check out the URL
>   for more information.

I modified the query to return the raw values and got Free = 587,896 and Total = 1,052,256. My altered query:

```
SELECT Free = cFree.cntr_value, Total = cTotal.cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters cFree
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_performance_counters cTotal ON cTotal.object_name LIKE N'%Memory Manager%'
    AND cTotal.counter_name = N'Total Server Memory (KB)                                                                                                        '
WHERE cFree.object_name LIKE N'%Memory Manager%'
    AND cFree.counter_name = N'Free Memory (KB)                                                                                                                '
    AND CAST(cTotal.cntr_value AS BIGINT) * .3 <= CAST(cFree.cntr_value AS BIGINT)
     AND CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('edition') AS VARCHAR(100)) NOT LIKE '%Standard%'
```

dbo.sp_BlitzCache (@BringThePain = 1) displays 316 rows, all apparently built-in SSRS housekeeping statements. Is it more likely that:

1. I have a problem as described at
   https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/too-much-free-memory/, or
2. The WHERE clause of the sp_Blitz query needs tweaking to avoid a false positive in this circumstance

Comment: It also seems odd that the cntr_value columns are being CAST to BIGINT in the WHERE clause when they are already BIGINTs, but this probably doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: #2, I reckon, and it looks like Tara has logged a bug with them. Also, these diagnostic scripts from vendors require interpretation, and should not be taken at face value. Good on you for questioning the results. That's a good sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [logged a bug](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/412) for it over on the [SQL Server First Responder Kit repository](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) on [Github](https://github.com/). You can check it for status and also add to it as needed.

Comment: FYI - this has been fixed in the dev branch, and we'll merge it to master in August.